# In Three.js, how to replace geometry normal with normal map completely

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

How do you replace geometry normal with normal map completely?  I am provided normal map and geometry from my work.  I am not allowed to change these files.  The goal is to just use normal map normal instead of geometry normal.  However, I can't find a way to achieve this since every way I tried was geometry normal dominating and the triangles are all obvious.  The only time I was able to achieve using normal map to replace geometry normal and render smooth surface was through custom shaders.  Is there any other way to use built-in shader but with normal map only?

```
            <mesh geometry={geometry}>
              <meshStandardMaterial
                attach="material"
                normalMap={normalMap}
                map={texture}
              />
            </mesh>
```

Comment: The closest thing I can recall is this: https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_normalmap_object_space . See in the source code what happens to "normal" attribute.

Comment: It turned out it is the .obj file issue when I use OBJLOADER.  I loaded the file as a string and manually create a geometry to fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it is the .obj file issue when I use OBJLOADER. I loaded the file as a string and manually create a geometry to fixed this issue.